# How to preserve and plot ID features not relevant to the testing set?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a data set with a number of columns of data relevant to deciding if a particular sales opportunity will result in a sale or not. There is also a leading column with an ID indicating which opportunity the row represents. I have chosen to exclude the row from one-hot encoding and feature analysis by simply slicing it off the front of array like so:

```
num_feature_columns = len(feature_extract.columns) - 1

X = feature_extract.values[:, 1:num_feature_columns]

y = feature_extract.values[:, num_feature_columns]
y = y.astype('int')

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.5, test_size=0.5, random_state=0)
```

i.e. X[0] will be a row with ID information still included, and X_train[0]/X_test[0] will only have classification relevant columns (the remainder).

My problem/question is, after results have been computed, I would like to retain and graph/illustrate these IDs so as to provide an indication of which sales opportunities were found to be most and least likely to be classified as. My current graph is as follows:

```
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
plot_model_summary(y_test, y_pred, "LR_plot.png")
```

How can I modify the plot summary to include the ID for at least a handful of its data points? Would I have to carry it through in the test set somehow? Or is there a way I can join it after the fact to a data point using the original feature set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could leave the IDs in the `X` array, carry them through `train_test_split` but then not use them in fitting and predicting, for example:

```
model.fit(X_train[:, 1:], y)
model.predict(X_test[:, 1:])
```

Then all the IDs are still in `X_train` and `X_test` so your plotting function can make use of them.